# Plotting sum of fields in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code for graphing the sum of a series of numerical columns. This should return a stacked bar chart where the contribution of each column is a different colour.

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(extrafont)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)

ggplot(data, aes(x = `Location Group`, 
                 y = Medical + Wages + `Rehab Cum` + `Invest Cum`,
                 fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

This is coming up with the error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'variable' not found`.

I'm not sure what would cause this, the formatting could have easily be copied and pasted from one of a hundred other cases here. Libraries included in case of conflicts (but I doubt that would be the case)

Sample data would be

```
Medical Wages `Rehab Cum` `Invest Cum`
    <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
1    1230 10360        1234          200
2     245  9782        2345          300
3    2234  6542        3456            0
4    5564  1234        4567          400
5      13   357           0            0
6     987   951           0            0
```

Comment: What is your `data` variable ? Can you post a minimal set of data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Updated OP with sample data. They're just numbers

Comment: It also has columns too which make the question more clear. It will make it easier for others to learn from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ggplot2 doesn't understand what `variable` is. The key to ggplot2 is remembering that each aspect of your plot should be represented by a column in your data.

So in this case, you don't need to give four different columns to your `y` mapping—ggplot2 will automatically stack variables if they overlap each other (`geom_bar` has the default `position = "stack"`). Instead, you want one column in your data for the `y` value and another for the colour each part of the bar should be (`fill`).

Using `fill = variable` is correct: you want the bars to be shaded according to which variable is being plotted. But `variable` needs to actually be a column in your dataset. So you want it to look more like this:

```
`Location Group`        variable        value
---------------------------------------------
location1               Medical         20
location1               Wages           30
location1               Rehab Cum       45
location1               Invest Cum      60
location2               Medical          5
location2               Wages           15
location2               Rehab Cum       55
location2               Invest Cum      90
```

Then `x` is mapped to `Location Group`, `y` is mapped to `value` and `fill` is mapped to `variable`.

You can get your data into this shape using [`gather`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html) :

```
library(tidyr)
data = data %>% gather(variable, value, Medical, Wages, `Rehab Cum`, `Invest Cum`)

ggplot(data, aes(x = `Location Group`, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: This pretty much did it. Only change I had to make was storing the first line as a variable and entering that into the second line. Thanks!

Comment: Whoops, yeah—I wasn't planning to re-type the plot code when I started 